# matlab: about eps range error

Tags: matlab, eps

I have a question about eps in matlab. 
I need to know if eps, rounding error, is a error defined like a uniform error and if it is defined as a half range or full range?
Thank you.

Comment: I can't really understand your question.  The Matlab documentation for eps seems very clear and straightforward to me, perhaps you can edit your question and be a bit more precise about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

From the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html).

Eps is defined as the distance from 1.0 to the next highest floating point number. It is not going to give you a rounding error, but rather the exact distance between two numbers.